# Retornar uma tabela em JSON usando criação de Elemento (Não posso usar Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

Ao inves de retornar a tabela em html, retornar em JSON e montar a tabela usando as funcionalidades de criação de elemento (document.createElement) e de inserção e remoção da árvore DOM.

Preciso de um help com essa questão, podem me ajudar ?

Atualmente meu código esta assim:

```
<table class="table table-dark table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">#id_armas</th>
    <th scope="col">Nome Arma</th>
    <th scope="col">Ação</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `armas`";
$busca = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($busca)) {
  $id_armas = $array['id_armas'];
  $nomearma = $array['nome_arma'];
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $id_armas ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $nomearma ?></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="color:#ffffff" href="editar_armas.php?id=<?php echo $id_armas ?>" role="button"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; Editar</a>
      <?php if ($_SESSION['nivel'] == 1) { ?>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="color:#ffffff" data-confirm='Tem certeza que deseja apagar esse item?' href="deletar_armas.php?id=<?php echo $id_armas ?>" role="button"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>&nbsp; &nbsp; Apagar</a>
      <?php } ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  //abrindo novamente a tag php e fechando a {} do wilhe apos o td pois o laco vai adicionar elementos ao TD.
} ?>
</tr>
```

e preciso fazer isso so que em json e adicionando a tabela na arvore dom

```
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var table = document.getElementById('tabela');
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');

      table.appendChild(tr);

      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = 'teste';
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      td.innerHTML = 'teste';
    }
    ajax.open("GET", "conteudotab.php");
    ajax.send();
  }
```

Comment: Vc quer criar a tabela toda ou só as linhas do PHP?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Quero criar a tabela toda, que sempre que for adicionado no banco um registro ele crie